# Newly installed Light, wiring issues. Won’t turn off

Tags: electrical

I ran a new plug into my bathroom from my lights. I secured all my neutrals together and all my power together except for the lonesome black wire that’s running to the switch.

When I reinstalled my light and connected it to the wire going to the switch nothing happened but when I connected it to all the other blacks it turns on but it won’t turn off.

I know I’m missing something and it could be simple or difficult !

[image]

Comment: Sounds like you screwed up your switch loop.  Can you provide pictures of the ceiling box and switch box?

Comment: Kk the picture isn’t the greatest and I also forgot to mention that it’s old wire so its not colour coded.

Comment: You'll first need to identify the two wires going from the ceiling light to the switch,  the always hot and the neutral. You'll need a volt meter.

Comment: So it’s hard to tell with that photo. But you will see a single wire by it’s self. That’s the one going to the switch (hot) the neutral is wired right now with all the other neutrals

Comment: Where on our planet are you?

Comment: Where's the other wire for the switch?  A switch needs an always hot and a switched hot.

Comment: This part concerns me: "I ran a new plug into my bathroom from my lights"...

Comment: Like I mentioned before. There are just 2 wires going to the switch which I haven’t touched. The load is in the box for the light. The neutrals are all wires together and the load is wired with the new plug I installed. I have the lonely wire that isn’t connected to anything and that is the wire going to the switch along with the neutral. I’m not really an electrician and not very good at explaining this. If anything I will take better photos tomorrow since I am not at my home at the moment.

Comment: So when I add the power (black) to the wire going to the box, nothing happens. When I connect it the wires (load) that is also connect to the plug the light stays on but it won’t turn off.

Comment: You have one of those voltage tester wands?  Find which of the black wires has no juice when you turn the switch off. Connect that to the light.  You've got your wires mixed up somewhere.

Comment: A switch has 2 wires, not 1. One of the wires is probably black and the other is probably white. *Neither of them is Neutral!* Now - which *two* wires go to your switch?

Comment: Your error is assuming wires are color-coded.  But think about it.  Just here, we have 3 wire functions: neutral, always-hot and switched-hot.  There are only 2 wire colors (because of how cables are made).  In actuality, white/gray are neutral, but can be re-marked to be a hot and 90% of the time "the last guy" failed to re-mark.  Any kind of hot is any other color, and you don't know which except by context/how it's hooked up presently.

Answer (score 4):

Wire it like this.

[image: SWITCH LOOP with FEED THROUGH]

Note that *not all white wires are neutrals*. One of them is part of the switch loop. Once you have identified it, mark both ends of it with black tape or paint.

If you can't tell which white wire is the one going to the switch, it is the white wire that comes into your ceiling light junction box through the same hole, or in the same cable, as the wire you've been calling the "lonesome black wire that’s running to the switch".

If you still have trouble understanding how this circuit should work, get your library to send you a book on do-it-yourself home wiring, and read the section on switch loops.